# How does AirTag achieve the same accuracy when there is an obstruction?

Tags: rf, bluetooth

I'm trying to figure out how AirTag achieves the same accuracy when there are objects inbetween the tags and iPhone.

Traditionally, if we are using Bluetooth, the RSSI value drops when we place an object inbetween (glass, concrete walls). There is a formula to calculate distance using RSSI value, but that only works in an open area.

It seems that when placing an object inbetween the AirTag and iPhone, the range will drop but the accuracy is not affected, as if the AirTag knows there are objects in between. How does Apple achieve this?

Comment: what sort of objects? a bus?  a cow? a cardboard box?

Answer (score 2):

Apple's AirTags and iPhones have had UWB (Ultra Wideband) Ranging technology for several years. Instead of depending on Bluetooth signal strength to estimate distance between the tag and the phone, this radio protocol actually measures the time-of-flight of the signal. It's somewhat analogous to LIDAR, but uses 6-10 GHz radio waves instead of laser light, and instead of passive reflection there is an active response from the target.

Because it does not rely on signal strength to estimate distance, the accuracy isn't severely impacted by attenuating obstructions such as walls, as long as there is still sufficient signal to detect the pulse. Here's an [article](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/what-is-ultra-wideband-uwb).

Comment: so the ToF protocal only works with UWB but not Bluetooth?

Comment: Correct. ToF accuracy depends on short pulses (or very fast modulation) of the UWB signal. The newest Bluetooth protocols support direction-finding, but not single-link ranging, and neither is available in consumer devices yet.